# "error: cannot find -l" when building with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am trying to implement a code to stream a video using QMediaPlayer.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget* vw = new QVideoWidget;

    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/media/dimo/New Volume/Media/Video/anime/[AnyAnime.com] Boku no Hero Academia - Ova 02 [LQ].mp4"));
    vw->setGeometry(100,100,300,400);
    vw->show();
    player->play();
    qDebug() <<player->state();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And this is the pro file:

```qmake
QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = videoplayer
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        dialog.cpp

HEADERS += \
        dialog.h

FORMS += \
        dialog.ui
```

It gives me this error :

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lpulse-mainloop-glib
:-1: error: cannot find -lpulse
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @Ahmad Magdy What is your Qt version ?  i think multimedia not exist before Qt 4.2 check [Qt version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_version_history)

Comment: Is qt properly installed on y our machine? Do you have the file pulse-mainloop-glib.lib on your machine. If you do not then that explains why the linker is not finding it.

Bob